# For an integer $n>2$, let $S_n$ denote the sum of the products of the integers from $1$ to $n$ taken three at a time. Find $S_{10}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation

For an integer $n\ge3$, let $S_n$ denote the sum of the products of the integers from $1$ to $n$ taken three at a time. (For example, $S_3=1×2×3$, $S_4=6+8+12+24$). Find $S_{10}$.

Although the problem asks just $S_{10}$, but it would be nice if you present a general formula of $S_n$.
It is quite evident that problem involves combinatorics and sequence & series.
Here's my advances until now:
Firstly I would like to make sincere apologies for not listing down my attempts to solve the problem.

**First Attempt**
I firstly looked over theory of equations and analysed that the problem asks something similar to *sum of roots taken three at a time for a n-degree polynomial*
$$p(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}...+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$$
with $\alpha_i$ as root of the above equation.
So we need to frame a decic equation with roots $\alpha_i=i$ over index i=1 to 10 i.e. $i\;\epsilon\;\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$. 
The equation is thus $$k(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)(x-6)(x-7)(x-8)(x-9)(x-10)=0$$ where $k \;\epsilon\; \mathbb{R}$
It is not very feasible way to reach the solution but still I proceeded.
As we just know the roots the equation if reduced to general form will give us the desired result.
Exploiting $(x-a)(x-b)=x^2-(a+b)x+ab$
We have equation as:
$$k(x^2-11x+10)(x^2-11x+18)(x^2-11x+24)(x^2-11x+28)(x^2-11x+30)=0$$
For the sake of convenience we set $t= x^2-11x+24$
$$k(t-14)(t-6)t(t+4)(t+6)=0$$
$$t(t^2-36)(t^2-10t-56)=0$$
$$t^5-10t^4-56t^3-360t^2+2016t=0$$
We are interested in coefficient of $x^7$
As only t^5 and -10t^4 contribute to x^7
Using Multinomial Theorem we get:\
coefficients are $-\frac{5!}{3!1!1!},-\frac{5!}{2!3!0!},-\frac{4!}{3!1!0!}$
On adding we get them -50
On applying root relation we get 50 which is not true.
I have miserably gone wrong somewhere.
Please guide
Second Attempt is not worth mentioning.
Thanks

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.

Comment: That sounds like a fun problem.  Have fun working on it.

Comment: I improved a little your question, please continue improving it, otherwise you probably won't get help here.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A001303

Comment: Thanks @GerryMyerson

Comment: Maybe after you've digested what is at that link, you will be able to write up and post an answer to your own question. That's allowed, indeed, encouraged here.